# how to using dynamic database connection with middlewere laravel passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I removed the database connection information from the env file and database.php file.
And I set the database dynamically with each request from the client.
I do this in main middleware

```
$origin = $request->header('Origin');
\Config::set(['database.default' => 'mysql']);
\Config::set(['database.connections.mysql.host' => '127.0.0.1']);
\Config::set(['database.connections.mysql.database' => $origin]);
\Config::set(['database.connections.mysql.username' => 'root']);
\Config::set(['database.connections.mysql.port' => '3306']);
```

I have no problem with the login and the token is created. But in other actions, I get a 401 error
In fact, the passport calls the connection information to the database from the env file or database.php. But we want to do this through middleware, or we can set the database information for it before checking auth: api.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Passport access default DB. If you would like to use dynamic database add below code in the boot method of your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
{

    Config::set('database.connections.pgsql.database', 'newdatabase');

    DB::purge('pgsql');
    DB::reconnect('pgsql');
}
```